# Using Master Theorem to prove a recurrence with f(n) = Θ(n/logn)

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, recursion

I'm trying to use the master theorem to solve the recurrence:

$$T(n) = 4T\left(\frac{n}{5}\right) + \Theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$$

I'm having trouble understanding how the $\Theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ factors into the solution, and what case to use to justify it. I've only worked with examples where $f(n)$ isn't some order notation.

is the fact that $\frac{n}{\log n}$ is not polynomial mean that this equation cannot be solved by the master theorem?

I'm confused as to what $$f(n) = \Theta\bigg(\frac{n}{\log n}\bigg)$$
means, instead of:$$f(n) = \frac{n}{\log n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The "non-polynomial" nature of the function doesn't matter. Here, we have the parameters
$$
a = 4\\
b = 5\\
f(n) = \Theta(\frac{n} {\log n}).
$$

Without considering $f(n)$, the recurrence has the solution $\Theta(n^c)$ where $c= \log _b a \approx 0.861$.

Now, let me ask you: which case of the Master Theorem does this lead to? Can you compare $n^c$ with $f(n)$ and tell which grows faster?

**Added**  Your comment is exactly right. Forget about the $\Theta(.)$ for the time being,and think only about $f(n)$ as you did.

Comment: in a comparison, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{n^{0.861}}{\frac{n}{logn}} = 0$. This means that $\frac{n}{logn}$ must grow faster than $n^{0.861}$. Does this mean case 3? because it must mean that $f(n) = \Omega(n^{c})$? I guess I'm confused about what $f(n) = \Theta \big(\frac{n}{\log n}\big)$ means instead of $f(n) = \frac{n}{\log n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Master Theorem can indeed be applied here. As a hint, can you see why for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have that:
$$
n^{1 - \epsilon} = O(\tfrac{n}{\log n})
$$

Comment: I can see that $n^{1-\epsilon} = O(\frac{n}{logn})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. We are comparing $n^{log_{5}4} = n^{0.861} to \frac{n}{logn}$. I just don't know where to go from here or what case this would apply to.